# How to get long value from this date format "MMM dd, yyyy" on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I got response from Server as below

`<reminder><text>Hello Dude!</text><date>June 2, 2011</date></reminder>`

I parsed the info successfully. Now i need to add the info on blackberry reminder.

I used below code:

```
try
{

    Event _event;

    String Calenderevent = "Hello Dude.";

    EventList eventList = (EventList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.WRITE_ONLY);

    _event = eventList.createEvent();

    long l= HttpDateParser.parse("June 2, 2011");

    _event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE,Calenderevent);
    _event.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, l);
    RepeatRule rule = new RepeatRule();
    rule.setInt(RepeatRule.FREQUENCY,RepeatRule.YEARLY);
    _event.setRepeat(rule);
    //If you need to repeat the event then use repeatrule.

    _event.commit();

    Dialog.alert("Calendar event success.");
} 
catch (PIMException e)
{
    Dialog.alert("Exception: "+e);
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

When I saw in Blackberry calendar, the info show in Dec 31, 2011

The problem occur is in below line.

`long l= HttpDateParser.parse("June 2, 2011");`

It returns -1 value.

How to get long value from this date format "MMM dd, yyyy" on blackberry.

Pls help me.

Comment: I think your dates in the wrong format looking at documentation at http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html I know nothing about the blackberry environment though, I imagine you can use other date functions built into Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joel noticed, you date format is not supported by `HttpDateParser`. One possible solution would be to convert your date to one of formats that `HttpDateParser` supports and then parse it with `parse()` method.

This code converts your date to **Wdy, Mon DD YYYY HHMMSS** format first and then parses it.

```
    String date = "June 2, 2011";       
    String time = "120000"; // desired time HHMMSS

    long l = 0;

    try {
        StringBuffer sbDate = new StringBuffer();

        // append WEEKDAY. weekday is not relevant for the HttpParser.
        sbDate.append("Sun, ");

        // remove comma after month
        int commaIndex = date.indexOf(","); 
        sbDate.append(date.substring(0, commaIndex));
        sbDate.append(date.substring(commaIndex+1));

        sbDate.append(' ').append(time);

        l=HttpDateParser.parse(sbDate.toString());

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // the date is in wrong format
    }
```

From the tests I made, **Wdy** is not taken into account by `HttpDateParser`. It returns the correct result with any valid weekday. This make sense for me, since what is really needed is DAY, MONTH and YEAR.

Comment: Thank u friend. Your code is perfectly worked. Thank u so much.